# How to transform a fullscreen HTML5 video?

Tags: javascript, css, html, video

I was able to transform a normal, non-fullscreen video element with this CSS-rule:

```
transform: rotate(9deg) !important;
```

However, when I put the video fullscreen, the rule gets magically overwritten by user-agent CSS-rules:

[image: user-agent CSS-rules]

So I guess what I am asking is if I can somehow override even the user-agent rules? By the looks of it the transform property is overdriven as it is strikethrough, but yet the video won't rotate.

Comment: Rotate a video in fullscreen? I don't know if it is possible, but if I become an user I will hate the developers that make it... For what purpose is that? Maybe there is another solution

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Ehh I just want to know if it is possible. Could maybe write some script to prank my friends with.

Comment: FF doesn't behave like that

Comment: @Kaiido Hmm you are right, Firefox rotates the video even if it is fullscreen. So is this Chrome limitation or is there some special way to do this for Chrome?

Comment: @dangor suggestion's to draw it to a canvas first is feasible but you will loose the controls and every other stuff that make the `<video>` element is what it is. I tried to find a way to overwrite the video's `requestFullScreen` (via `webkitfullscreenchange`) to append a new one on its parent, But it fails since we need a user's gesture, and that the pointer event which occurs on the fullscreen button of the video's controls is being blocked and such not reliable. Might be possible to attach a fake button though and use the same logic of calling `requestFullScreen` on the video's parent.

Answer (score 0):

did you try specifying a css rule, similar to the one enforced by the browser? So, looking at the pasted code above, maybe something like this:

```
video:-webkit-full-scren {
    transform: rotate(9deg) !important;
}
```

I did some similar stuff for range inputs, and I successfully overwrote the default browser styles. Maybe it works here too.

Furthermore, I also did some fullscreen tweaking of similar sorts. I wanted to remove the controls when in fullscreen, since I implemented my own. I just used this and it worked:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
    display: none !important;
}

::-webkit-media-controls {
    display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried: `video:-webkit-full-screen { transform: rotate(19deg) !important; width: 50%  !important; height: 50%  !important;}` In style section, but it does not seem to override anything either.

Comment: Can you maybe post a jsfiddle, so we can have a look?

Comment: hmmm, it seems it can't be done. Just can't overwrite the default styles for fullscreen. Perhaps there is something you could do. There's a library which uses canvas to load videos: github.com/gka/canvid You would first fullscreen the canvas element and then rotate the video element inside of the canvas, or even rotate the canvas itself. It might be worth a shot....